# In Android, how can I adjust widths and layout of elements based on the screen when density isn't working

Tags: android, screen-resolution

I have a list of item so the screen. Their size and padding depends on the screens size. I'm using density but on screens that have a high density but smaller size devices (such as the 2013 Nexus 7) it's treating the display like a 10 inch because of its density. To get the density I'm using:

```
float density = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
```

To test I'm doing this:

```
if(density >= 2.0){
     itemLayout.setPadding(0, 400, 0, 0);
}
else if(density >= 1.0){
     itemLayout.setPadding(0, 200, 0, 0);
}
else{
     itemLayout.setPadding(0, 200, 0, 0);
}
```

The 2013 Nexus 7 that I'm testing on shows it as a `2.0` so it uses the first `setPadding` but given the size I need it to use the lower setting.

Comment: Why aren't you using `android:layout_width="match_parent"`?

Comment: I'm having to use images and padding to make a grid and the way this has to be setup `match_parent` didn't work. It's a long complicated story... one that gave me a headache.

Answer (score 0):

If you have to fix it this way, you can use the `dimens.xml` file instead of using the density and the if-else style.

create `values` folders for different screen densities (example: values-xhdpi, values-xxhdpi). and have a good look at the options of [providing alternative resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources).